# Is there any way to force TextMate to cache files?

Tags: macos, textmate

I'm working with a Rails project over an AFP mount in TextMate. Every time TextMate becomes the active window, it spins for around 30s-1m, which is VERY frustrating. I've sampled TextMate when this is happening, and found multiple calls to `+[NSFileAttributes _attributesAtPath:partialReturn:filterResourceFork:error:]` to be the issue. Is there any way to eliminate these spins?

I'm the only one working on the files, so I don't really care about collisions with file changes(I wouldn't mind if the files were cached locally until I explicitly saved them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. There's a plugin for this --

[Remate](http://ciaranwal.sh/remate/)

BTW, what's going on is that TextMate is refreshing your entire source tree. This plugin will turn this off - the effect of which is that if you add new files to your source tree, you need to turn off and on the plugin (which is very easy, it's under the "Window" menu).

Comment: I was not expecting such a simple answer, but this works perfectly!